# Did Gavrilo Princip ever express regret for his actions during imprisonment?

Tags: world-war-one, assassination

After assassinating the Archduke Franz Ferdinand and his wife in June 1914; Gavrilo Princip spent just short of 4 years in Prison in Austria-Hungary before dying in April 1918 of tuberculosis. I was wondering since he lived to see the results of his actions did he ever express regret for his actions?

I have tried to find information regarding his time in prison, interrogations, possible letters to/from him, etc, but have not come up with much. I have read that he may have attempted suicide in 1916 while in prison.

Any insight regarding his time time in prison would be of interest to me.

Comment: According to the wiki article on Princip, his psychiatrist said he did not feel responsible for WWI, that it was bound to happen. What more are you looking for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Serb conspirators did express regret at the deaths of what they considered "innocent" third parties, but basically felt that they did what they needed to do on behalf of their beloved Serbia.

[Gavrilo Princip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gavrilo_Princip), the main assassin, did express regret at his trial for killing the Archduchess" (the wife of Archduke Franz Ferdinand), but asserted that he was a Yugoslav Nationalist aiming for the freedom of his people.

Another conspirator, 17-year old Vaso Cubrilovich, told the United Press in the 1950s,

> "If I had known what tragic results there would have been in world history, I would have thought twice about my actions. I would not today come out and defend Austria, but using assassination was not the right way to accomplish our political goals. But the war would have broken out anyway, because the system of international tensions would have made it inevitable." (The foregoing is my rough translation from German sources.)

Comment: You should give the source for this  Čubrilović quote.

Comment: @kimchilover: For the record, it's in an old (1971) book called "German For Reading Knowledge," p.170, 2nd edition, by Hubert Jannach.